# Is there a finite non-Hermite commutative ring with unity?

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

A commutative ring $R$ with unity is Hermite if for all $x,y\in R$ there exists $t,u,v\in R$ such that $x=tu$, $y=tv$ and $(u,v)=(1)$. Is there a finite commutative ring with unity that is not Hermite?

This characterisation is taken from theorem 3 of:

Some Remarks About Elementary Divisor Rings, Leonard Gillman and Melvin Henriksen, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 82, No. 2 (Jul., 1956), pp. 362-365

Comment: +1: interesting question.  But -1 for using "cru" to stand for "commutative ring with unity".  Note that you have plenty of room to write this out.  I will "remove my downvote" when this cru business is remedied.

Comment: [For lazy people like me...](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1956-082-02/S0002-9947-1956-0078979-8/S0002-9947-1956-0078979-8.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to use this observation in a paper - may I acknowledge you? If you'd like me to use your real name, send me an e-mail, cmcq of-email-domain liv.ac.uk.

Comment: Since there are not many caracters, you can use it free of charge;)